# Print 2nd command line argument

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, command-line-arguments, nasm

I'm writing a code that prints out the 2nd argument of a program. I understand that `ebp+8` holds number of argument, `ebp+12` holds address of name of program and so on. So far I have:

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

SECTION .data
err1: db "Incorrect number of command line arguments",10,0

SECTION .text 
    global  asm_main

asm_main:
   enter 0,0
   pusha

   mov eax, dword [ebp+8]
   cmp eax, dword 2
   jne ERR1

   mov eax, dword [ebp+16]  ; prints 1st letter of 2nd argument
   mov al, byte[eax]
   call print_string
   jmp asm_main_end


 ERR1:
   mov eax, err1
   call print_string
   jmp asm_main_end

 asm_main_end:
   call print_nl
   popa                  ; restore all registers
   leave                     
   ret
```

The executable is called *lynarr*. When I execute `lynarr abcd`, I'm able to print the program name (ie *lynarr*) but I don't understand how to print the 2nd argument. I'm using redhat-linux and nasm 2.10.07. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dword [ebp+12]` is a pointer to an array of string pointers. The first element of that array is a pointer to the first string, the second element is a pointer to the second string etc. Each pointer is 32-bits (4 bytes) wide.

To get a pointer to the second string would require getting the pointer at `dword [ebp+12] + 4`. You can't do that directly in x86 addressing. You can do it by moving `dword [ebp+12]` into a register like *EAX*, add 4 to it (since a pointer is 4 bytes wide) and then dereference that to get a pointer of the second string.

Replace:

```
mov eax, dword [ebp+16]  ; prints 1st letter of 2nd argument
mov al, byte[eax]
call print_string
```

With:

```
mov eax, dword [ebp+12]  
mov eax, [eax+4]          ; EAX = pointer to 2nd argument
call print_string
```

This would print out the second argument. The first argument can be printed out with:

```
mov eax, dword [ebp+12]  
mov eax, [eax]           ; EAX = pointer to 1st argument
call print_string
```

Of course `mov eax, [eax+8]` would get the 3rd argument and so on.

You can't use `print_string` to print a single character in a register (like *AL*). *EAX* must be a pointer to a *NUL*(\0) terminated string.

---

Something else you can do is use [scaled index addressing](http://ece-research.unm.edu/jimp/310/slides/assem2.html) to step through an array (like your arguments):

```
mov ebx, dword [ebp+12]  
xor esi, esi            ; Index of first argument (index=0) 
mov eax, [ebx+esi*4]    ; EAX = pointer to 1st argument
call print_string
inc esi                 ; Next argument (index=1)
mov eax, [ebx+esi*4]    ; EAX = pointer to 2nd argument
call print_string
inc esi                 ; Next argument (index=2)
mov eax, [ebx+esi*4]    ; EAX = pointer to 3rd argument
call print_string
```

With this idea you can probably see how you can create a loop that goes through the arguments. I leave that as an exercise for the reader. This is another handy [quick reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20131228092838/http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall10/V22.0201-002/addressing_modes.pdf) for addressing modes.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to jump to `ebp+16` directly which I can now see is wrong. Also, I wasn't aware that `print_string` can't be used to print out AL. Thanks so much for this!

Comment: Yes, I saw that. You just had to dereference [ebp+12] first and then add 4. You were close in knowing that 4 had to be added to get to the next element. You just had to have the right pointer to begin with.

Comment: @Sally I've added a section regarding the use of scaled index addressing that you might find useful later on.

Comment: I haven't used `esi` or `edi` much yet but I can definitely see the utility! I'll make sure that I read up.

Comment: @Sally It will likely be something you will eventually touch on (especially if you are taking a course), and can be very useful for working with arrays. Good luck!